# Must positive operators be self-adjoint on real vector space?

Tags: linear-algebra

On real vector space , if positive operator is defined as operator $T$ such that

$$\langle Tv,v\rangle\geq 0$$

for all $v\in V$, is it possible to prove that $T$ is self-adjoint?

Comment: Side note: in many (but not all) contexts, the definition of *positive operator* includes the condition that $T$ is self-adjoint. As the answer by diracdeltafunc shows, this additional condition, when present, is not redundant.

Comment: @Bungo now I understand diracdeltafunc’s answer, but... why some definition omitted the self-adjoint condition?

Comment: Your title is totally wrong. $\Bbb R$ is not the notation for a general real vector space!

Comment: @Ted This is possibly a language issue: "over $\mathbb{R}$" would be correct, and it can be very tricky to remember the correct preposition to use if you're not a native speaker!

Comment: @diracdeltafunk  Yes, I agree. As a speaker of numerous languages, I find prepositions a daunting proposition. Why not just say a real vector space?

Comment: @TedShifrin thank you, i've updated the title.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

No. For example, let $T$ be rotation by a small angle (like $\pi/100$) in $\mathbb{R}^2$. Then $T^* = T^{-1} \neq T$.